# drag drop between Swing & JavaFX

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, javafx-2

I want to do drag/drop from swing component to JavaFX 2 component is that posible?

My application is swing and use a JFXPanel to display a LineChart, i want to drop data from a Jtable to the chart.

I try to set the transfer handler on the JFXPanel but that doesn't seems to work.

Clarification:

```
setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler());
```

I just do that on the main JFrame to intsall a custom transfer handler, in the frame there a table and a JFXPanel with the LineChart, i can drop objects onto the table but not onto the chart.

Not sure if i need to implement something on JavaFX side, so that the chart in the JFXPanel also accept the drop.

Basically i just want to drop on any place of my window, the result will be the same in my case, the drooped object will be added to the underlying model.

Comment: please, provide code which didn't work for you

Comment: Not been a JavaFX developer, I'd say it would still be possible, as the DnD is handled by the platform.  It would be the same process as dragging something into the application from the native system

Comment: You will definitely need to [implement something on JavaFX side](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm).

Comment: @jewelsea , I have now implemented JavaFX side following that doc, and it works great, but will be nice that JavaFX Scene could delegate  drag/drop to the JFXPanel and be able to reuse the TransferHandler.